# Facebook FQL is deprecated, but there's no way to directly get friend_count with Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using FQL I can easily get the friend count of a user with:

```
SELECT uid,friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (<list of user ids/>)
```

But it looks like with Graph API, I have to make requests until the pagination runs out, and then count how many results were returned using something like:

```
array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => 'me/friends?access_token='. $token
)
```

I tried using

```
array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'relative_url' => 'me/friends?summary=true&access_token='. $token
)
```

but that didn't work. Is there a single Graph API request that can get a user's friend count? If not, how do I make a feature request?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook implemented this feature for the Graph API since the release of v2.1:

> /friends edge on the User object now provides access to total friend count. This is retroactively supported in v2.0 as well.

[Graph-API-v2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/)

Comment: See also this question for an example: [Get only the total_count of friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365285/get-only-the-total-count-of-friends-facebook-graph-api)